# Why does the condition for a planet to have an atmosphere has the $\frac{1}{6}$ in its $v_{\text{esc}}$ term

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, planets

My teacher told me the condition that a planet has an atmosphere is$$v_{\text{rms}}\le \frac{1}{6}v_{\text{esc}}$$ When I ask for derivation, he told me that it is from integrating the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution from $0$ to $v_{\text{esc}}$ instead of $\infty$. i.e.$$v_{\text{rms}}^2=\frac{\int_{0}^{v_{\text{esc}}}v^2\cdot 4\pi\left(\frac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}v^2\exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}\right)dv}{\int_{0}^{v_{\text{esc}}} 4\pi\left(\frac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}v^2\exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}\right)dv}$$
but the value I get is hardly different from integrating from $0$ to $\infty$. Could someone please explain? Does the factor comes from integrating to $v_{\text{rms}}$ and I did it wrong, or is it from other analysis?

Comment: You need to integrate to a low cutoff for the integrals' ratio to scale as $v_\text{esc}^2$. For $v_\text{esc}\ll\sqrt{\frac{2kT}{m}}$, we can treat the Gaussian factor as constant, so$$v_\text{rms}^2\approx\frac{\int_0^{v_\text{esc}}v^4dv}{\int_0^{v_\text{esc}}v^2dv}=\frac35v_\text{esc}^2\implies\frac{v_\text{rms}}{v_\text{esc}}\approx\sqrt{\frac35}.$$As this is much larger than $\frac16$, your teacher has clearly oversimplified the derivation.

Comment: Also, your $\ge$ should be a $\le$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "[rule of thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb)". Few molecules have velocities more than a few times the RMS velocity, and only those few may escape. The factor of 1/6 is a rough guide to the point where the escape rate becomes small enough that the planet may retain a substantial atmosphere over geologic time.